# Upload with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, apache, upload

I'm creating a website, and I have a form to add a new post. I'm using an iFrame instead of ajax for a full support on IE (Ok, I know that IE is the most hated and one of the worst browser, but some noobs are using it). Basically, when I submit the form, it gives me an internal error (500).
Here is my form:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/css/ionic.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form" id="form" action="./addPost.php" method="POST">
         <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Title" class="AddPosttitle" name="title">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input class="description" type="text" placeholder="Simple Description (max 60 caracters)" maxlength="60" name="description">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <div>
                <span id='button_upload'>Image : </span>
                <input type='file' class="img" name="img">
            </div>
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <textarea placeholder="Full description" class="full" name="full"></textarea>
          </label>
            <div class="padding">
              <button class="button button-block button-positive submit-btn" type="submit">
               Submit
            </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <style type="text/css">
        .form {
            background: #FFF;

        }
    </style>
    <?php
    if (!empty($_GET['error'])){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
                var result = null,
                    tmp = [];
                var items = location.search.substr(1).split("&");
                for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
                    tmp = items[index].split("=");
                    if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
                }
                return result;
            }
            alert(findGetParameter("error"));
        </script><?php
    }
    ?>
```

I'm using the Ionic library, just because I love some components, but anyway, this is my `addPost.php` file :

```
<?php
try
{
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=something;dbname=someDB;charset=utf8', 'ID', 'LOL');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
   die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

$post = $_POST;
$img = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']));
$title = addslashes($post['title']);
$description = addslashes($post['description']);
$fullDesc = addslashes($post['full']);
// if (!empty($title) & !empty($description) & !empty($fullDesc) & !empty($img)) {

// }
// else {
//  // header("Location: form.php?error=Fill the form!");
// }

$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, description, img, fullDesc, likes) VALUES ('$title', '$description', hextoraw('$img')', '$fullDesc', 0)";
$db->exec($sql);
    // header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Location: form.php?error=$sql");
```

I don't know why there is an error. I think that it comes from the image, but I'm not sure. I'm still trying for an eventual solution, I'll edit my question if I find something (just to let you know!)

Comment: in the insert into posts there is an extra quotation. just to let you know.

Comment: Whatever `hextoraw` is, you can't call a function from withing a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should be using [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) for security:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (title, description, img, fullDesc, likes) VALUES (:title, :description, :img, :fullDesc, :likes)");

$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);
$stmt->bindParam(':img', hextoraw($img));
$stmt->bindParam(':fullDesc', $fullDesc);
$stmt->bindParam(':likes', 0);

$stmt->execute();
```

This can also help you by making easily reusable statements (see link).

Comment: Well, I have an unexpected issue, it gives me this : `Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /api/addPost.php:30  Stack Trace #0 {main} thrown is /api/addPost.php on the line 30` The line 30 is `$stmt->bindParam(':likes', 0);`

Answer (score 0):

If the 500 error displayed is the generic error page (without any stacktrace or detailed error message), look for the last lines of the error log file of your webserver, and post them here. We need more information about the error you have. Maybe a file access error ? Database error ?

Also, if you use the HEXTORAW Oracle function to convert an hex string to a binary data, you must be aware that HEXTORAW works with hexstring, not base 64 encoded string.
You should use http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php instead of base64_encode.

Answer (score 0):

You have misprint in the sql string:
    hextoraw('$img')**'**

Remove last quote